# Visual Studio update 16.8.1 build fails for runtime linux-arm

Tags: visual-studio-2019

after update to 16.8.1 my buid is not working
build command: `dotnet build -r linux-arm -c Debug`

Error:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.100\Current\SolutionFile\ImportAfter\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Solution.targets(27,5): 
error NETSDK1134: Creating a solution with a specific RuntimeIdentifier is not supported.
 If you want to publish for a single RID, specify the RID at the individual project level.
```

To confirm that i created new project (simply console .NET Core 3.1) with csproj like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    **<RuntimeIdentifiers>linux-arm</RuntimeIdentifiers>**
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="OpenCvSharp4.Windows" Version="4.5.0.20201013" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Same build command: `dotnet build -r linux-arm -c Debug`
And same error.

My colleague has VS 16.7.5 and by her works (was working on my VS before upgrade)

Thanks for any help, till solution i will try to downgrade my VS.